# Error Meta-data: {"dataFile":"resources/env1/data.json"}@scenarios/jsonformfiller.feature#5 TestStep implementation not found

Tags: java, json, cucumber, qaf, feature-file

**Error**

> Meta-data: {"dataFile":"resources/env1/data.json","description":"Data
> driven test that uses enter code herejson file to provide
> data"}@scenarios/jsonformfiller.feature#5 TestStep implementation not
> found. Please provide implementation or ensure 'step.provider.pkg'
> property value includes appropriate package.

**Step Definition**

```
    @QAFTestStep(description = "user is on google Web Page")
        public void step1() {
            
    try {    
            GooglePage googlepage = new GooglePage();
            googlepage.invoke();
            googlepage.waitForPageToLoad();
            System.out.println("I am on Google Search Page");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            
        }
        }
        @QAFTestStep(description = "user enters text {strText} in google search box")
        public void enterSearchText(String strText) {
            
            try {
                 GooglePage googlepage = new GooglePage();
                 googlepage.googleSearchTextBox.verifyPresent("google search TextBox");
                 googlepage.googleSearchTextBox.sendKeys(strText);
                System.out.println("I search for " + strText);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                
            }
        
        }
```

**Could not include the whole step definitons code here stack overflow warning me that i added too much code**

```
  Feature: Validate Web Form
  Scenario: Validate User is able to fill form using json Data File
   Meta-data: {"dataFile":"resources/env1/data.json","description":"Data driven test that uses 
   json file to provide data"}

      Given user is on clevermedia web form 
      When user enters first name '${firstname}' from json data file
      And user enters last name '${lastname}' from json data file
      And user enters zipcode '${zipcode}' from json data file
      And user enters message '${message}' from json data file
      And user clicks on submit 
      Then user should be able to submit form successfully
```

**Step Definition** - all feature file test steps are defined in the below step
definitions QAFTestSteps.

**TestNG Configuration for Test Execution**

```
  <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
   <suite name="QAF Demo" parallel="methods" verbose="0">
   <test name="QAF-BDD-Test">
      <parameter name="step.provider.pkg" value="com.qmetry.qaf.clevermedia.steps" />
      <parameter name="scenario.file.loc" value="scenarios/jsonformfiller.feature" />
      <parameter name="env.resources" value="resources/env1" />
   <classes>
     <class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.gherkin.GherkinScenarioFactory" />
   </classes>
  </test>
  </suite>
```

Does anyone see an error in my step in implementing the Data Provider ?  why am i
getting this error? All feature file steps are defined or have the corrosponding QAFTestStep. Testng configuration for the test execution included above also appears to correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gherkin syntax doesn't have support of meta-data. You can use [BDD2](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd2.html) syntax which is **superset of Gherkin**.
In BDD2 you can provide scenario metadata on top of scenario:

Feature File

```
Feature: Validate Web Form

@dataFile:resources/env1/data.json
@description:Data driven test that uses json file to provide data
Scenario: Validate User is able to fill form using json Data File
   Given user is on clevermedia web form
   When user enters first name '${firstname}' from json data file
   And user enters last name '${lastname}' from json data file
   And user enters zipcode '${zipcode}' from json data file
   And user enters message '${message}' from json data file
   And user clicks on submit
   Then user should be able to submit form successfully
```

For [BDD2](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd2.html) you need to use BDD2 factory instead of Gherkin factory. Refer [documentation](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-configuration.html#factory-class).

TestNG Configuration for Test Execution

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="QAF Demo" parallel="methods" verbose="0">
<test name="QAF-BDD-Test">
     <parameter name="step.provider.pkg" value="com.qmetry.qaf.clevermedia.steps" />
     <parameter name="scenario.file.loc" value="scenarios/jsonformfiller.feature" />
     <parameter name="env.resources" value="resources/env1" />
  <classes>
     <class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.text.BDDTestFactory2" />
  </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

However recommended is [BDD2](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd2.html), If you still want to use Gherkin syntax,  it doesn't have provision for meta-data or external test data. With QAF Gherkin factory supports  data provider with examples as below to stick with gherkin syntax:

```
Scenario: Validate User is able to fill form using json Data File
....
Examples: {"dataFile":"resources/env1/data.json"}
```